# How to organise this module pattern and elegantly deal with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, module, code-organization

I have couple of modules that do their own thing, but need them to sometimes access a property of one another (not that intertwined, just one json obj). Like so

```
var Bananas = (function() {

// Bananas.properties would look like this
// Bananas.properties = { 'color' : 'yellow' };

var methodToGetProperties = function() {
    API.get('bananas')
        .done(function(data) {
                Bananas.properties = data;
            }
    };

    var publiclyReturnProperties = function() {
        if (!Bananas.properties) {
            methodToGetProperties();
        } else {
            return Bananas.properties;
        }
    };

    var doSomethingBananas = function() {

        bananas.doing.something;
        bananaHolder.innerHTML = Bananas.properties;

    }

    var init = function() {
        doSomethingBananas
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        properties: publiclyReturnProperties,
    };

})();

var Apples = (function() {

var doSomethingApples = function() {
    apple.innerHTML = Bananas.properties.color;
};

var init = function() {
    doSomethingApples();
};

return {
    init: init
};

})();

Bananas.init(); Apples.init();
```

Now, the way I do it now is by simply revealing the methodToGetProperties, which returns the API call, and then work on using jQueries deferred method wherever I call it. But I feel this ruins my code by putting .done everywhere.

I've been reading up to singleton pattern and feel it might be the solution to my problem, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Or maybe implement a callback function in methodToGetProperties, but again not confident as to how.

Would kindly appreciate advice on how to organise my app.

Comment: Hi. Could you write an example of using the above-described objects? .done runs after the asynchronous call? how to initialize objects?

Comment: that's my question, at least part of it

Comment: or, if you mean how to initialize the modules? will do so

Comment: if the bananas.doing.something; waits until the completion of the request to the server I do not see any problems in that to not do so.